# The page must inherit from DelvingWare.AsyncControls.AsyncPage

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, multiple-inheritance

```
using DelvingWare.AsyncControls;
    public partial class buildCheck : System.Web.UI.Page    
    { 

     }
```

Presently  ,The above code , I need inherit the  "DelvingWare.AsyncControls.AsyncPage"   class into "buildCheck" ,
1.Here directly writing for the  "System.Web.Ui.Page,DelvingWare.AsyncControls.AsyncPage "
2. I got error ,and also i am using  only the " DelvingWare.AsyncControls.AsyncPage" class I got some other error ,i want both class inherit into "buildCheck" page ...can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear.
The controls you are using expect your base class to be `DelvingWare.AsyncControls.AsyncPage`

You cannot have two base classes in c#.

Comment: No. AsyncPage would most probably be derived from `Page` itself, so you will get all that you need from Page even when you use AsyncPage